# Python - TypeError list (not "str") to list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Задача такая: У меня есть `BMP` картинка с размером `896x116`. Я открываю её и задаю двум переменным эти данные. Так же, мне нужно разделить `896` на `0x3` и `0x80`, что в конце пересылается как `0x380 = 896`; также и с `116`

```
path = "logo.bmp"
img = Image.open(path, "r")
img.load()

width = img.size[0] # получаем 896
height = img.size[1] # получаем 116

def bytes(num): # с помощью этого получаем 0x3 и 0x80
    return hex(num >> 8), hex(num & 0xFF)
```

Далее, я хочу сделать следующие:

```
address = [0x80, 0x03, 0x94] 
value = bytes(width)[1] # 0x3
value2 = bytes(width)[0] # 0x80

send = (address + value)
```

И получаю ошибку

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str“) to list
на send = (address + value)
```

Как избавится от этой ошибке?

Comment: Вы приводите width к байтам, потом берете от них элемент. Отдельный элемент коллекции байт - целое число. Прикрепить целое число к списку (address) просто оператором сложения нельзя.

Comment: @insolor тогда как правильно прикрепить, не подскажите?

Comment: сейчас нет, далеко от компа.

Comment: @insolor тогда буду ждать

Comment: @insolor обратите внимание что `bytes()` здесь переопрелено. Кроме того даже встроенный `bytes()` не так работает. @Insider `bytes` это встроенное имя в Питоне: избегайте переопределять его несовместимым способом.

Comment: Какая у вас версия Питона? Какой результат вы хотите: целое число (int), байты (bytes)?  Возможно вы хотите `struct.pack('!H', 896)` или если входное число имеет нефиксированный размер, то [`int2bytes(896)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28524760/4279)

Comment: @jfs 2.7, нужно целое число, чтобы отправлялось по `SPI`; `spi.xfer(address + value)`, т.е получается `spi.xfer2([0x80, 0x03, 0x94, 0x03])`

Comment: По поводу добавления в список jfs вам уже ответил. Пара советов: не используйте имя `bytes` - это имя встроенного типа Python. Для перевода целого числа в набор байт вместо велосипеда лучше использовать метод `int.to_bytes()`, а результат приводить к списку. В вашем случае это будет выглядеть примерно так: `values = list(width.to_bytes(2, byteorder='little'))` ("little" означает порядок байт от младшего к старшему (из 0x380 получаются байты `[0x80, 0x03]`), если нужно наоборот, то пишите "big"). Потом просто берете `values[0]` и `values[1]` и используете как вам нужно.

Comment: @insolor для Python 2.7 - использовать `struct.pack`?

Comment: fail. Не обратил внимания, что вопрос по Python2. Да, похоже что более-менее универсальный вариант - использовать `struct.pack`.

Comment: @insolor попробовал вот так  `value = struct.pack('>i', width) send = hwidth1 + value[3] spi.xfer2(send)` и получаю ошибку `Non-Int/Long value in arguments`

Comment: @Insider в Питоне строки и числа имеют разный тип и `b"\x03"[0]` возвращает строку, а не целое в Питоне 2. Вы хотите послать 2-й младший байт из `width`? `b = (width >> 8) &0xFF; spi.xfer2(address + [b])`. Возможно удобней с `bytearray()` работать, чтобы создать данные для посылки, если `spi.xfer2(bytearray(b"\x80\x03\x94\x03"))` работает.

Comment: Для преобразования `int` в список байт можно такой вариант использовать: `value = [ord(item) for item in struct.pack('>i', width)]`

Comment: @insolor `value = [ord(item) for item in struct.pack('>i', width)]
    send = hwidth1 + value[3] 
    spi.xfer2(send)` к сожалению не работает.

Comment: Insider, через append добавляйте значение в список, как в ответе jfs

Comment: @insolor  `hwidth1 = [0x80, 0x03, 0x90]
    value = [ord(item) for item in struct.pack('>i', width)][3]
    send = hwidth1.append(value)
    spi.xfer2(send)` пишет мне ошибку `can only concatenate list (not 'int') to list`

Comment: http://ideone.com/SuqIhZ

Comment: Не знаю почему, думал что ответ к вопросу дал jfs. Прошу прощения.

Comment: @insolor теперь, cannot convert argument to integer..  странно это все

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43679/discussion-between-insider-and-insolor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Питоне списки, числа, строки представлены разными типами и операция сложения для смеси этих типов не определена. Можно складывать списки со списками, строки со строками, числа с числами, но нельзя перемешивать иначе вы получите `TypeError` как в вопросе.

[@Avernial показал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/553350/23044) как можно добавить число (`value`) к списку (создавая временный список налету), то есть заменить `address + value` на `address + [value]`. Кроме этого в вопросе много других ошибок (определение `bytes`, ожидание что `[]` возвращает целое для строк).

[Судя по коду](https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev/blob/511db0d036f3ec6592ee2bef1a3b30fbd90a5d07/spidev_module.c#L391-L487), `spi.xfer2()` функция, [упомянутая в комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553192/python-typeerror-list-not-str-to-list#comment713097_553192), ожидает последовательность байт, представленных как целые числа, поэтому как

```
width = 896 # 03 80
byte = (width >> 8) & 0xff # 03
result = spi.xfer2([0x80, 0x03, 0x94] + [byte])
```

так и

```
#!python2
width = 896 # 03 80
_, byte = struct.pack('<H', width) # "\3"
result = spi.xfer2(bytearray("\x80\x03\x94") + byte)
```

должны одинаковую последовательность байтов производить.

В обоих случаях можно вызывать `address.append(byte)` вместо сложения, если `address` в других местах не используется (если его можно изменять в этом месте) и посылать `address` напрямую вместо `send`: `spi.xfer2(address)`.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите добавить значение к списку, то можно сделать вот так:

```
send = address + [value]
```

Comment: Метод `append` добавит элемент к исходному списку (`address`) и вернет `None` (которое попадет переменную `send`).

Comment: Да верное замечание.